# How to allow a user to connect only from a specific IP?

Tags: authentication, vps, ubuntu-18.04

The scenario is as follows: I have a VPS (Droplet) in Digital Ocean (DO), I connect via putty-ssh, however I must have another user enabled with root privileges and with password access (without ssh), this is because When there are connection problems through putty-ssh, I must enter through my DO account, and access the droplet console using that user with a password to fix the problem. This usually happens every time I restart the server and I can not connect with any user from putty, the connection is rejected. The solution is simple, restart ufw and everything solved.

However I open a door for hackers who can easily break this user password with all privileges. The idea is to allow this user to connect only from my personal IP, but the Ubuntu firewall only allows IP / port / application rules, no user can be referenced. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After much research and testing and more tests, specifically with the commands **telnet** and **login**, I discovered something I did not know; when the SSH service is active, only ssh connection with a private key is allowed, no other connection is allowed, even with ssh+password. This feature, either integrated into Ubuntu, or is implemented by Digital Ocean, I guess the first.

Considering this, there is no problem that raised in this question; no one can connect to the server unless you have the private key, and if you also only allow the ssh connection from a specific IP, the security is very good. By configuring the firewall in this simple way, it will be sufficient:

```
ufw status verbose

To          Action      From
--          ------      ----
8000       ALLOW IN   Anywhere
6666/tcp   ALLOW IN   15.15.15.15
8000(v6)   ALLOW IN   Anywhere (v6)
```

Port 8000 for incoming requests from HTTP and HTTPS clients, which will be managed by django, and any port other than the default 22 for ssh, specifying the private IP of my computer, I can only connect from my computer with the corresponding private key. We will also have to modify the ssh configuration file which is the file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** replacing port 22, **PasswordAuthentication no** and restarting the service with **service ssh restart**.